# ConnectivityManager getActiveNetworkInfo null pointer exception

Tags: android, android-service, android-networking

I see occasionally null pointer exception in connectivity manager. From intent service I check network state by isOnWIFI(this). Exception occurs at line cm.getActiveNetworkInfo(). It's strange because I check for null before I call this.
Note: Permissions are set.

```
public static boolean isOnWIFI(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        return cm != null
                //here occurs NullPointerException
                && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
                && ((cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) != null && cm.getNetworkInfo(
                        ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).isConnected()));

}
```

Any thoughts why this happen? I can't debug it because it's only occasional from bugs reports. Only solution I see is to put it into try catch block. Thanks.

Comment: Which permissions are set?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

Comment: I am not sure but you can check with adding one more permission android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE

Comment: As you can see it fails at cm.getActiveNetworkInfo(). My problem is not that I can't check wifi. Problem is that there is occasionally null pointer exception.

Comment: Did you find an answer for this? I get the same problem and I also have a null check. Every answer I see are totally missing the point...

Answer (score 6):

are you Checked the api in that they are mentioned if there are no active connections they are simply returning null i think this is ur problem.

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html
         #getActiveNetworkInfo()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#getActiveNetworkInfo%28%29)

Answer (score 6):

android_dev is right. The problem in your code comes from `cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).isConnected()));`

Yes! you check `cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) != null` before, but by calling `getNetworkInfo()` a second time, android goes and fetches the Network info a second time, only this time it does not encounters an active network returning null this second time.
The thing is, not because you called `getNetworkInfo()` a millisecond before and didn´t get a null, means you are not going to get it a millisecond after

Answer (score 3):

```
Try this. Read more here
```

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/managing.html

```
public static boolean isOnWIFI(Context context) {

 ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) this.getSystemService(context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

 if(cm != null){

   NetworkInfo networkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

   boolean isWiFi = networkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI;

   // if user is connected to network
   if (isWifi) {  
      return true;

   }else {
     return false;

   }

 }
 else{
    //cm is null 
    return false

 }  
}
```

Comment: I don't see difference. I also check cm!=null and then I get cm.getActiveNetworkInfo null pointer exception. As I said, it's only occasional

Comment: @vandzi: do you have debugged the code ?
Where from your activity you are calling this method? Your context is null as far as I guessed because there is no issue in code.

Comment: @haris Can ConnectivityManager ever be null? Do we really need a check for cm!= null ? What cases can it be null?

Comment: This answer does not address the problem at all.

Answer (score 3):

`getActiveNetworkInfo`  returns null if no there's no default connection available as per the docs >> [getActiveNetworkInfo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#getActiveNetworkInfo%28%29) .So what I'd advise you to do is  check for the networks, each individually as below

```
NetworkInfo WiFiInfo = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
NetworkInfo mobileInfo = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
```

then check if they are available

```
if(mobileInfo != null &  mobileInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting() || WiFiInfo != null  & WiFiInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting())
    {
        //do your task here
    }
else {
     //show an alert dialog or something    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When i was working with services, this solved my issue.. Before i was just using !info.isConnected()  but that was not enough

```
 ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo info = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if(info==null || !info.isConnected()) {
            stopSelf();
            return;

        }
```

Answer (score -1):

I just made one template with this kind of problem , now it works good. You can try this code , I tried it on many devices and there is no problem. [`getActiveNetworkInfo()` problem](http://code.google.com/p/android-template-for-eclipse/downloads/list) . Before I tried `getAllNetworkInfo()` and I do not understand what is wrong but `getAllNetworkInfo()` is working stupid on some devices.

Comment: ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) c.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE); NetworkInfo[] netInfo = cm.getAllNetworkInfo(); for(NetworkInfo nix : netInfo) { 
         if(nix.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE)
        if (nix.isConnected()){
         isAnyNetworkAvailableType = "MOBILE";

Comment: This is crazy , when I start device and internet is not on application works good. When I turn on internet application is still good it detects change but if I turn internet of application do not recognise change. Also application detect change when you turn on but not off .